# Use slash in config.yml variable

Tags: php, symfony, guzzle, guzzle6

I'm trying to set a variable in the `config.yml` of `8p Guzzle` bundle (https://github.com/8p/GuzzleBundle) like this:

```
guzzle:
    clients:
        identity_api:
            base_url: "%some.url%:5000/v2.0"
```

and doing a typical get:

```
$client = $this->container->get('guzzle.client.identity_api');
$response = $client->get('/users')
```

but I am receiving an error telling me that the url requested is:

```
http://somedomain.com:5000/users
```

I think is something with the `slash`, I'm trying to scape with backslash but nothing.

Comment: `$client = $this->container->get('guzzle.client.identity_api');` - isn't it `guzzle.clients` in the YAML file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My mistake, following http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/latest/quickstart.html#making-a-request

```
base_uri            URI             Result
http://foo.com      /bar            http://foo.com/bar
http://foo.com/foo  /bar            http://foo.com/bar
http://foo.com/foo  bar             http://foo.com/bar
http://foo.com/foo/ bar             http://foo.com/foo/bar
http://foo.com      http://baz.com  http://baz.com
http://foo.com/?bar bar             http://foo.com/bar
```

I have to remove the `slash` of the users request.

```
$client = $this->container->get('guzzle.client.identity_api');
$response = $client->get('users')
```